# Generate localized javadoc

Tags: locale, javadoc

I would like to know if there was a simple way of generating localized javadoc : I would like to have translated (for example in french) title and keywords instead of "return", "parameter", "class" in the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by Matt Ball, you can provide the `-locale` option to javadoc to influence some things. The problem is that tools.jar only contains the default English and additionally one Japanese (`ja`) and one Chinese (`cn_ZH`) translation.

I just tried the Chinese one, and it works: it writes **抛出： JSchException** instead of **Throws: JSchException**.

So you would have to translate these to your language (if you don't want one of these).

Some years ago I created an Esperanto translation of those resources for the then-current version (1.2 or such), if you are interested I could dig them out. (But it seems now they are using another format.)

Comment: Thanks. I have also found an old site where someone had done a partial translation of the ressources but it was also for an old version : I took a look at tools.jar and it seems that the format is different now. I will see if I have time to make a translation (but since the specs often change, it seems a bit useless).

Comment: The information that "tools.jar only contains the default English and additionally one Japanese (ja) and one Chinese (cn_ZH) translation" is outdated. I don’t know when exactly it changed.

Comment: @Bolpat Yes, it's somewhat expected that an answer from 2011 is not quite up-to-date. Feel free to add an edit proposal, if you have more up-to-date values.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, it seems to support a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is the javadoc [`-locale`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#locale) option, though I'm not sure that it changes keywords like `return` and `class`. There is only one, non-localized set of keywords in Java, so I don't think it makes sense to alter those in the JavaDocs anyway.

> Specifies the locale that javadoc uses when generating documentation. The argument is the name of the locale, as described in java.util.Locale documentation, such as `en_US` (English, United States) or `en_US_WIN` (Windows variant).
>
> Specifying a locale causes javadoc to choose the resource files of that locale for messages (strings in the navigation bar, headings for lists and tables, help file contents, comments in stylesheet.css, and so forth). It also specifies the sorting order for lists sorted alphabetically, and the sentence separator to determine the end of the first sentence. It does not determine the locale of the doc comment text specified in the source files of the documented classes.