# Javadoc "ı" "i" issue

Tags: java, encoding, javadoc

I'm from Turkey and I try to generate Javadoc files. But when I do, the i's in the file written as "ı". Some Turkish letter. Do you know any way to solve this issue?

i.e: " tıtle> Uses of Class Processor tıtle>"

Comment: what do you use to generate the JavaDoc files? Do you use an IDE to do that or some external tool?

Comment: Is your keyboard configured to interpret input as English? If you're running Windows, check `intl.cpl`.

Comment: Is your documentation English only? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538586/generate-localized-javadoc.

Comment: Interesting blog post [The infamous Turkish locale bug](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug)

Comment: I'd have a look at the [locale settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#locale) for the javadoc tool (assuming you are using the JDK).

Answer (score 0):

write "-locale en_US" in VM options( Javadoc menu,third page)