# Multilingual Android Sdk Documentation

Tags: android, documentation, translation, javadoc, multilingual

We have a social responsibility project aiming encourage young people to learn mobile application development. The main problem we face mostly is language. Most of the young people in our country don't have sufficient english knowledge to be able to search or learn something in english. That's why our one of the biggest difference from the world wide tutorial/learning sites is being in native language.

As a supporter of the project in the technical side, we answer questions, write blog posts and try to help people learn mobile application development in their native language. One of the problems i face with while helping people is the inability of providing official references(in native language) about the responses we gave. This problem pushed me thinking about translating whole android sdk documentation to our native language :) I know it's a huge job, we may try to crowd-sourcing it i dont know but the thing i want to ask here is just suggestions about implementation of such a project.

What kind of technology would you use, how would it be possible to stay synch with the recent versions of the sdk. Do you think the current android sdk documentation pages auto-generated completely? Is it just java-doc? How to support multi-languages with java-doc? Or with any other way?

I hope questions will not be closed being unrelated, it is a completely technical question.

Thanks everyone

Comment: "Do you think the current android sdk documentation pages auto-generated completely?" -- yes. "Is it just java-doc?" -- the JavaDocs certainly are, probably using some custom doclet that is aware of Android-specific annotations like `@hide`.

Comment: It is worth to check this bro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538586/generate-localized-javadoc

Comment: _How to support multi-languages with java-doc?_    
I don't know the Android DK yet, but as CommonsWare mentioned, a customized doclet. (Or a taglet) that uses external resources. Background: for a past Java (SE) project, I did a taglet which imports HTML and/or images files from elsewhere into the Javadocs.  (But that's not viewable by IDEs).  
In your case, by pointing to different "doc-files" for instance, specific to each language, you could build as many API javadoc versions, respectively.

Comment: After asking this question i came across with the Microsoft Community Translation program which aims to translate msdn with the help of the community and serve better local content than the machine translated content. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/translate/

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

I guess not only do you want the Java documentation, but also the tutorials and everything that is provided by developers.android.com.

I think you should ask Googe / the developers of Android directly for support, e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers). I'm pretty sure they like the idea and support you with that by giving you access to some feed that keeps the tutorials up-to-date.
An independent solution would be to implement a crawler for developers.android.com and track the changes yourself. Yet I don't know how much effort you can/want to spend on that.

For the crowdsourcing: I did a project once for crowdsourced writing error correction, where we used [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/). It is used for translation too. It is quite easy to build your custom tasks for the crowd and to automate the whole process. They provide a Java API, for example. It costs some money, but is quite cheap in comparison to professional translators.

Just some suggestions...